# The Birthday paradox - how to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from numpy.random import randint
import random
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bday(c):
    trials = 5000
    count = 0
    for trial in range(trials):
        year = [0]*365
        l = False
        for i in range(c):
            bdayp = randint(1,365)
            year[bdayp] = year[bdayp] + 1
            if year[bdayp] > 1:
                l = True
        if l == True:
            count = count + 1
    prob = count / trials
    return prob


for i in range(2,41):
    a = bday(i)
    print(i,a)
```

As you can see, I generate the number of people in the class along with the probability that they share a birthday. How can I plot this so that I have n (number of people) on the x-axis and probability on the y-axis using matplotlib.pyplot?

Thanks.

Comment: @Selcuk is right; you should post your code, and not images of your code. Here is the documentation you are looking for: https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Fixed the presentation of code. I've been trying to figure out how to use plt but I am still having problems with defining the x and y axis.

Comment: Did you look over the link above? If you did, you would've noticed the following: ```plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])```, which prints the x and y-axis.

Comment: @FelipeFaria how do you add a function to the y axis? Adding individual numbers doesn't help me.

Comment: Notice how there is a comma separating both lists. What that code is effectively doing is plotting [1,2,3,4] as the x-axis, and [1,4,9,16] in the y-axis. In other words, you are plotting the points (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16). Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've linked in the comments the proper documentation to your problem. For the sake of you finding your own solution, perhaps looking at the following might make more sense of how to go about your problem:

```
def func(x):
    return x * 10

x = []
y = []
for i in range(10):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(func(i))

plt.plot(x, y)
```

The above can also be achieved by doing the following:

```
def func(x):
    return x * 10

x = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(x, func(x))
```

Here is the documentation for [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html); both will plot the following:

[image]

Comment: Absolute legend. It worked like a charm. Thanks so much! I didn't know I could use np.arange for the plot

Comment: My pleasure -- glad you found your own solution. Numpy's ```arange``` function is very effective for these sort of problems.